# I can not get a message from the database without loading all message

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I first loaded all the messages from the database. Then I chose what I need.

But it's not correctly loading all messages.

```
var ldetails = _context.RegistrationUsers.Include(i => i.ListFriends).ThenInclude(z=>z.MessagesDetails).SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserName == Context.User.Identity.Name);
```

I wanted to load only one message by criterion but I constantly get an error.
Please show me a ways to do it.

I have tried:

```
var ldetails = _context.RegistrationUsers.Include(i => i.ListFriends).ThenInclude(z=>z.MessagesDetails.SingleOrDefault(g=>g.TextMessage == messagesDetail.TextMessage)).SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserName == Context.User.Identity.Name);
```

But I get an error. My code looks like:

```
public class RegistrationUser
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PMId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName ="varchar(16)")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(16)")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(480)")]
        public string Token { get; set; } 




        public ICollection<ListFriend> ListFriends { get; set; }


        public RegistrationUser()
        {
            ListFriends = new List<ListFriend>();

        }
    }


public class ListFriend
{
    [Key,Column(Order = 0)]

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }    
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName ="varchar(16)")]
    public string UserFriendName { get; set; }



    public ICollection<MessagesDetail> MessagesDetails { get; set; 
    }

    public ListFriend()
    {

        MessagesDetails = new List<MessagesDetail>();
    }


}


public class MessagesDetail
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    [Key,Column(Order = 0)]
    public int PMIdMes     { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar(240)")]
    public string  TextMessage{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(16)")]
    public string SenderUser { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(16)")]
    public string CatcherUser { get; set; } 
}


//My method

[Authorize]
public async Task DeleteMessage(string frend ,MessagesDetail 
messagesDetail)
        {

            var ldetails = _context.RegistrationUsers.Include(i => 
            i.ListFriends).ThenInclude(z=>z.MessagesDetails.
 SingleOrDefault(g=>g.TextMessage == messagesDetail.TextMessage)).
 SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserName == Context.User.Identity.Name);


//.....
         }


I expect to receive a message for the condition:

g=>g.TextMessage == messagesDetail.TextMessage;
```

Comment: "...i get an error..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Error messages aren’t there just for fun, they actually say what’s wrong and they should always be included so we don’t have to guess what’s wrong

Comment: Please see [ask] and improve your question accordingly.

Comment: Failed to invoke hub method 'DeleteMessage'.
System.InvalidOperationException: The ThenInclude property lambda expression 'z => {from MessagesDetail g in z.MessagesDetails where ([g].TextMessage == __messagesDetail_TextMessage_0) select [g] => SingleOrDefault()}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var pdetails =  _context.RegistrationUsers.SingleOrDefault(c=>c.Password==Context.User.Identity.Name);    
var nlk = _context.Entry(pdetails).Collection(n => n.ListFriends).Query().SelectMany(n => n.MessagesDetails).Where(z => z.TextMessage == messagesDetail.TextMessage).ToList();
```

IT work!

Comment: thk anyway, for new method i check was worked, but my solution more compact and also work

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to filter in `Include` or `IncludeThen` which is not supported. You would have to create a projection by using `Select`:

```
var ldetails = _context.RegistrationUsers.Select(x=>new RegistrationUser
{
  PMId=x.PMId,
  UserName=x.UserName,
  Password=x.Password,
  Token=x.Token,
  ListFriends=x.ListFriends.Select(q => new ListFriend
    {
      UserId=q.UserId,
      UserFriendName=q.UserFriendName,
      MessagesDetails=q.Where(a => a.TextMessage == messagesDetail.TextMessage).ToList()
    }).ToList()              
}).SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserName == Context.User.Identity.Name);
```

Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1833) for more information.