# Change the code to improve the performance (eager loading)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

i have this code for find `UserInfo`and find role of user in `UserRole` and find role info from `Role`.

I am using Identity Table.

this is my code:

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult<List<User>>> GetuserList(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var userDto = new UserDto();
    var users = await userManager.Users.Include(x => x.UserRoles).ThenInclude(t=>t.Role).ToListAsync();

    return users;
}
```

But this code is not good for performance Because in first step it get all user info `userManager.Users`, second step find all `user role` info and find all user info again `.Include(x => x.UserRoles)` and find all role info `.ThenInclude(t=>t.Role)`.

I just need `roleID` from `UserRole` and `roleName` from `Role`.

What should I do to load Required info not all of them?

**Update Code:**

i write This code :

```
var users = userManager.Users.Select(x => new UserDto
        {
            UserName = x.UserName,
            Email = x.Email,
            Family = x.Family,
            Name = x.Name,
            Password = x.PasswordHash,
            PhoneNumber = x.PhoneNumber,
            RoleId = x.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault(t => t.UserId == x.Id).UserId
        });
```

but still i need to find `RoleName` on `RoleTabel` but it can not use the `Include` in `Select` . how can i use find `RoleName` ????

Comment: You can use Projection with `Select` to get your `roleID`. Refer to this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55509350/i-can-not-get-a-message-from-the-database-without-loading-all-message/55512660#55512660

Comment: @RahulSharma i need to find `RoleName` with `UserRole` Table . how can i use include in projection ?

Comment: Can you specify what would be the return you want? Is it just these two fields? RoleId and RoleName?

Comment: @jpgrassi no . all `User Info` and `RoleName` and `RoleId`

Comment: Well, I assume that `User` is your derived class from `IdentityUser`, correct?

Comment: @jpgrassi yes . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select from a nested child table references, the approach I use is to select into an anonymous type to build an efficient query, then further reduce from that into the DTO.

For example:

```
var users = userManager.Users.Select(x => new 
{
    UserName = x.UserName,
    Email = x.Email,
    Family = x.Family,
    Name = x.Name,
    Password = x.PasswordHash,
    PhoneNumber = x.PhoneNumber,
    Role = x.UserRoles.Select(r => new { r.RoleId, r.Role.RoleName}).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToList()
.Select(x => new UserDto
{
    UserName = x.UserName,
    Email = x.Email,
    Family = x.Family,
    Name = x.Name,
    Password = x.PasswordHash,
    PhoneNumber = x.PhoneNumber,
    RoleId = x.Role?.RoleId,
    RoleName = x.Role?.RoleName
}).ToList();
```

You can get by with a single `.Select` though this may lead to less efficient SQL as each inner `.FirstOrDefault()` etc. would likely re-JOIN the UserRole / Role tables. This way the first `.Select()` builds the SQL for a nested structure containing the child data we need, then the second operates across the resulting POCO anonymous types to construct the flat DTO to return.

One last thing, when using `.First()`/`.FirstOrDefault()` you should use an `.OrderBy()` clause to ensure a predictable result if you only want one entry out of a possible many.

Also, given that we are using `.Select()` to map our output, you do not need to use `.Include()` to select from related entities. You also don't need the `.Where()` clause inside your User.UserRoles. (User.UserRoles will only contain UserRoles for that UserId) Where you will see `.Where()` clauses used is when joining loosely associated tables from the DbContext. Directly related entity relationships via mapped FKs is preferable.

Edit: Given every user may not have a role, in the second `.Select()` you'll need to use the "?." operator to retrieve the Role ID and Name. This will mean the DTO Role ID must be null-able. If you want to default to a RoleId of 0 or such instead, you can use `RoleId = x.Role?.RoleId ?? 0`

Comment: Was going to post an answer, as the existing ones missed all the important points. But there's no need now :).

Comment: hi man . when i using your code it show me this error : `Message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` it can not find role and rolename of users. it work just for one user not list of users

Comment: hmm, my bad, it is a .FirstOrDefault which assumes every user has at least one role associated to them, some users may not. EF will handle the "OrDefault" with an outer join, but the second `.Select()` will need to explicitly handle it. I'll update the answer.

Comment: thank you  man . it work . but can you explain to me in this code `Role = x.UserRoles.Select(r => new { r.RoleId, r.Role.RoleName}).FirstOrDefault()` How do it find which role for which user ?

Comment: When the relationship between User and UserRole is set up it will be something like `User.HasMany(x => x.UserRoles).WithRequired(x => x.User)` where the UserRole will be configured to map to user via a UserId. When you access User.UserRoles EF knows that the UserRoles to return will be for that one User via the UserId automatically. This can be explicitly mapped in your code, or EF can map relationships automatically via conventions. Without that mapped relationship you would have to Join on DbContext.UserRoles and link the IDs manually.

Answer (score 1):

Until you call `ToListAsync()` which executes your query on data source, you can shape your query with `Include`, `ThenInclude`, `Select`, `Where`, etc.. features.

What you should do is just combine your first quesry with the projection on your update.

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult<List<User>>> GetuserList(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var userDto = new UserDto();
    var users = await userManager.Users.Include(x => x.UserRoles).ThenInclude(t=>t.Role)
       .Select(x => new UserDto
        {
            UserName = x.UserName,
            Email = x.Email,
            Family = x.Family,
            Name = x.Name,
            Password = x.PasswordHash,
            PhoneNumber = x.PhoneNumber,
            RoleId = x.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault(t => t.UserId == x.Id).UserId
        })
      .ToListAsync();

    return users;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `Include` if you are doing projection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes

Comment: @jpgrassi I wasn't aware of this. Thanks for notice.

Answer (score 0):

I have something sort of similar that hopefully helps. It performs just fine

```
      if (users != null && users.Length > 0 )
        {
            foreach (var item in users)
            {
                var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(item);
                if (userRoles.Contains("Foreman"))
                {
                    CW.AddRange(db.CrewMemberForeman.Where(x => x.AssignedForemanId == item).Select(x => x.CrewMember).OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).ToList());
                }
            }
        }
```